# Caculating amount from two table different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to subtract from two the different table.
And result is third table.
This is my query SQL:

```
SELECT
     a.ma
    ,a.Ten
    ,a.Dvt
    ,ISNULL(SUM(a.Soluong),0) AS Nhap
    ,ISNULL(SUM(b.Soluong),0) AS Xuat
    ,(ISNULL(SUM(a.Soluong),0)-ISNULL(SUM(b.Soluong),0)) AS ton
    ,a.Batch,a.MaKe 
FROM tbNhap a 
    INNER JOIN tbXuat b ON a.ma=b.ma and a.Batch=b.Batch
GROUP BY
    a.ma
    ,a.Ten
    ,a.Dvt
    ,a.Batch
    ,a.MaKe 
HAVING a.Batch LIKE '3217101711' AND a.ma LIKE '11020000000031'
ORDER BY
     SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 5, 2)
    ,SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 3, 2) ASC;
```

I want to show the same photo. Please.

[image]

Comment: Please add the expected result as text / code

Comment: do NOT USE images of data or the wanted result. copy/paste that into into formatted text instead. there are sites to help make fixed ascii tables if need e.g. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Your `having` clause should be a `where` clause instead (move it up before the `group by`). A having clause is designed to evaluate aggregated values, which you don't need for those conditions.

Comment: And what is the result you currently get? Would be helpful to compare result "as is" with result "expected"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the order between SUM and ISNULL, otherwise if you have just one NULL in your sum, the sum will be NULL and then ISNULL will change it into 0. The SELECT would be like this:

```
 SELECT
      a.ma
     ,a.Ten
     ,a.Dvt
     ,SUM(ISNULL(a.Soluong,0)) AS Nhap
     ,SUM(ISNULL(b.Soluong,0)) AS Xuat
     ,SUM(ISNULL(a.Soluong,0)-ISNULL(b.Soluong,0)) AS ton
     ,a.Batch,a.MaKe 
 FROM tbNhap a 
     INNER JOIN tbXuat b ON a.ma=b.ma and a.Batch=b.Batch
 GROUP BY
     a.ma
     ,a.Ten
     ,a.Dvt
     ,a.Batch
     ,a.MaKe 
 HAVING a.Batch LIKE '3217101711' AND a.ma LIKE '11020000000031'
 ORDER BY
      SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 5, 2)
     ,SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 3, 2) ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you! But the results is wrong. It is not same me to like

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want:

```
DECLARE @tbNhap TABLE
(
    [id] INT
   ,[ma] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[Ten] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[Dvt] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[Soluong] INT
   ,[Batch] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Make] VARCHAR(4)
);

DECLARE @tbXuat TABLE
(
    [id] INT
   ,[ma] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[Ten] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[Dvt] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[Soluong] INT
   ,[Batch] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Make] VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO @tbNhap ([id], [ma], [Ten], [Dvt], [Soluong], [Batch], [Make])
VALUES (1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 1200, 3714101711, 'Q209')
      ,(1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 1000, 3217101711, 'R202')
      ,(1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 770, 3217101711, 'C203');

INSERT INTO @tbXuat ([id], [ma], [Ten], [Dvt], [Soluong], [Batch], [Make])
VALUES (1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 500, 3217101711, 'R202')
      ,(1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 100, 3217101711, 'C203')
      ,(1, 11020000000031, 'PTZ5S DN', 'PC', 350, 3217101711, 'C203');

SELECT a.ma
       ,a.Ten
       ,a.Dvt
       ,SUM(ISNULL(a.Soluong,0)) AS Nhap
       ,MAX(b.Xuat) AS Xuat
       ,SUM(ISNULL(a.Soluong,0))- MAX(b.Xuat) AS ton
       ,a.Batch
       ,a.MaKe 
FROM @tbNhap a 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ma
          ,Ten
          ,Dvt
          ,Batch
          ,make
          ,SUM(ISNULL(Soluong,0)) AS Xuat
    FROM @tbXuat
    GROUP BY ma
            ,Ten
            ,Dvt
            ,Batch
            ,make
) b
    ON a.ma=b.ma 
    and a.Batch=b.Batch
    and a.Make = b.make
 GROUP BY
     a.ma
     ,a.Ten
     ,a.Dvt
     ,a.Batch
     ,a.MaKe 
 HAVING a.ma LIKE '11020000000031'
  ORDER BY
      SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 5, 2)
     ,SUBSTRING(CAST(a.Batch AS varchar(10)), 3, 2) ASC;
```